# What is the benefit of the theory of categories?

Tags: category-theory

I know the definition of a category and know several examples. But I have not studied the theory of categories.

Much of mathematics I studied can be written as a category and a functor.

But for me, a category is just an organizational language. What is the merit of studying category theory?

What can I obtain by reading Mac Lane's book?

Is it necessary to learn category theory to be a good mathematician, especially for number theorists, algebraists, and topologists?

Comment: Category theory is far more than just an organization language. And yes, basic categorical notions are foundational for (large parts of) algebra and topology.

Comment: I don't know the answer but if I had to learn Cat Theory I'd start with a user friendly book like Awodey's one.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312605/what-is-category-theory-useful-for

Comment: I know this is going to bring me problems, but I really loathe category theory...and about your last quetiopn I sincerely think the answer is a huge **no** .