# Application of Category Theory

Tags: category-theory

Can anyone give an example of a simple application of category theory? Not a very mathematical one, just one that shows how it can be used. Something for example that can be solved by just getting the limit or something (preferably in the category of sets or finite sets). I searched but could not find a published one. I understand that to apply category theory on something you need to be very specialized on that area. Thank you

Comment: you might look at these questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312605/what-is-category-theory-useful-for  and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19325/most-striking-applications-of-category-theory (heavier maths there)

Comment: This question has been asked a lot of times on math.SE. Vote to close.

Comment: It has been asked a lot and got few actual answers other than those involving topological spaces and vectors. If the OPs could understand topological spaces then they would not ask this question

Comment: Then please narrow your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look through [this book](http://math.mit.edu/~dspivak/CT4S.pdf) about category theory for scientists.

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much